# How to throw error if server is not pingable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that currently ping some servers. if the server is ping-able, the script with scp some files into that server. I want to add a portion so that if the server is not ping-able, the script with throw an error message.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-copy-id localhost
#Getting list of server
server_list=${cobbler system list}
for server in ${server_list} ; do
   dns_names=${cobbler system report --name${server} | grep -i "dns name" | awk '{print $4}')
   for dns_name in $dns_name} ; do
       ping -q -c2 ${dns_name} 
       # syncing files to servers
       if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
          scp -r /root/.ssh/ ${dns_name}:/root/
          break
       fi

      # Throw error msg if the server is not pingable
         [code here]
      # Could anyone please help me start on how to do this task?
   done
done
```

Comment: how about using `else` condition ? try something like `if ping ..... ;do scp..... ;else echo error; fi`

Comment: You can also test the `ping` status directly in the `if` statement: `if ping -q -c2 ${dns_name}; then StuffToDoIfPingable; else StuffToDoIfNOTPingable; fi`. Oh, and your definitions of `server_list` and `dns_names` use `${` inappropriately. Recommendation: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) (although some of the mistakes in your script ... confuse it).

Answer (score 0):

On surface, looks as if the goal is to avoid ssh to non-accessible hosts which will result in long (or maybe infinite) timeout.

Worth noting that it is possible to have functional ssh/scp to servers which can not be pinged. This may be true for server behind firewalls, proxies, etc.

Alternative approach will be to impose a timeout on the scp

```
scp -o'ConnectTimeout 5' ...
# OR
timeout 5 scp ...
```

Security note: Doing 'scp' to the complete ~/.ssh folder can be risky. Usually, you want to copy your public key, and keep your private keys at your local machine. Consider reducing scope of copy to only files that are needed.

Comment: Not only that, but `.ssh` can contain *multiple* keys and configuration files that don't need to be (or *shouldn't* be copied).